# Why is the "Mark Occurrences" feature in Eclipse automatically disabling itself?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, highlight, eclipse-indigo

I never had this issue with Eclipse before (Eclipse Classic 4.2.2, Indigo) but it started happening on my new iMac recently, that it stops highlighting similar occurrences or variable names, etc. Then it automatically starts working just fine.

Needless to say its a pain when it doesn't show the multiple occurrences of variable names and I have to find them using Find.

I was wondering if there is a sequence of keys which I press by mistake which causes it? I haven't find an answer to this anywhere else yet.

Attached is the screenshot from the Preferences. As I edit this question, again the Mark Occurrences is greyed out and I'll have to check it again to make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A work around for this is to click on e.g. the Outline view, and then click back on the editor.  The mark occurrences should start working again.  I don't know of a long term fix.

Comment: I tried this before posting this question but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Pity.  Beyond that, all I can suggest is search for/log a bug with https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ and hope for the best.

Comment: Again this early morning it is greyed out as in the picture above. Such a pain. I even reinstalled Eclipse couple of days ago.

Comment: It seems the newest version of Eclipse is littered with new bugs.